# Location of Recent apps screenshots in Android

Tags: java, android, android-recents

*Where does the OS saves the screenshots it takes of the recent apps?* I have searched for the finding the directory location but couldn't find any info. I have also looked through Android source code and found that Google is calling `toggleRecentApps()` using handler but couldn't reverse engineer the code further.

Does anybody knows the location/directory of the screenshots of Recent apps?

Regards